# add a javascript query dynamically change the button label in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a button named "Freeze".
I want to create a dynamic action that changes the name from "Freeze" to " "UnFreeze" on click.
I have set the static id for the button as "Freeze_StaticID" and then created a dynamic action for the click event.
Under True condition, I want to add a javascript query for the same.
Can anyone please tell me the query I need to add for the same?
I tried adding the code below but it didn't work.

```
$("#Freeze_StaticID").attr ('value', 'UNFREEZE')
```

Comment: well, `$("#Freeze_StaticID").html ('UNFREEZE')` will change the text, if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: There might be a simpler solution which is a bit more declarative. Instead of changing the button label, why don't you create 2 buttons ? One "Freeze" and one "Unfreeze". Your dynamic action can then show one and hide the other on click.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I had this idea in mind but am looking for an option where I don't need to create another button, also it would be very simplified if we could just add a js query to change the label, otherwise, I have the option of creating 2 buttons, hiding one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the HTML implementation. When it's a `<button>` element, then it works like this: `$('#Freeze_StaticID').text('UNFREEZE')`

Btw: It's jQuery behind the scenes. You can toggle the browser's developer console (F12) and execute the appropriate getter and see what the result is for:

```
$('#Freeze_StaticID').text();
$('#Freeze_StaticID').attr ('value');
```

When undefined is returned, it's the wrong approach because it should return the current title of the button.

Details:

- https://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [JavaScript API for Apex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/item.html#setValue)

```
apex.item("Freeze_StaticID").setValue("UNFREEZE");
```